# How can I type 小篆characters that are not in the FANG ZHENG XIAO ZHUAN TI FONT?

Tags: writing, seal, fonts

By intalling the FANG ZHENG XIAO ZHUAN TI FONT I've been able to type 小篆 characters. However there are many chacters which don't change when the font is applied to them. For the more modern characters this is understandable. For instance "們" doesn't change into seal script because it's a modern invention and there is no seal script for it. But there are many characters that DO have a 小篆form, but I can't get it to display. For instance the characters 飛，鬥，光，首ect, etc. don't display in seal script. Is there any other 小篆font I can use? I know I can cut and paste pictures of seal script characters, but I would much prefer them to be actual text.

Comment: [Trying this website](https://www.qqxiuzi.cn/ziti/fzxzt/), [I can't reproduce your problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9aVMH.png)

Comment: Hi drooze. Thanks for your response. That website is good for converting modern characters to xiao zhuan (and other scripts), but it only outputs pictures. I'm hoping to be able to use a font to display the xiao zhuan.

Comment: You misunderstood my comment. I was pointing out that FANG ZHENG XIAO ZHUAN has no problem displaying those characters, which means that you either have a limited edition of the font, or you're inputting the characters incorrectly. If you don't describe exactly how or where you're inputting the characters or what edition of the font you're using, then we cannot solve your problem.

Comment: https://www.cns11643.gov.tw/downloadList.jsp?ID=2&ID2=20 說文解字 True Type Download by 全字庫

Answer (score 0):

You must enter **simplified** characters to reproduce Xiaozhuan characters using this font. If you want to display 飛，type in 飞 instead.